# Unset Twig Session Variables

Tags: session, variables, twig

How can we destroy the session variable in twig?
I can get session variables by app.session.get('$name').
And I want to destroy it afterwards for some purposes.

Thanx!

Comment: If you need session variables that only exist for the next request (2.0) or till their first read (2.1/master), use flashes.

Comment: hi Maerlyn. Thanks for your comment. That's what I actually did to handle my purpose. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash Messages are the right way to do this.

Symfony2 Cookbook example:

```
{% if app.session.hasFlash('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ app.session.flash('notice') }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

For more information check the Symfony documentation [flash messages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages).